# JSP form Submission with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, spring, forms, jsp

While self-learning I came to a point I have to submit form.

I have controller QuestionController.java

```
package com.java1.project.question;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
public class QuestionController
{
    @Autowired
    private QuestionService questionService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addques", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addQuestion(@RequestBody Question question)
    {
        questionService.addQuestion(question);
    }
}
```

I have tested my controller using post-man. If data post in below JSON format, then my controller is entertaining it and data is getting saved in the DB.

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/addques
Method: POST
Header: Content-Type = application/json
Body: 
{
    "question" : "some long question",
    "ansList" : [
        {
            "providedOption" : "some option 1",
            "isRightOption" : false
        }, 
        {
            "providedOption" : "some option 2",
            "isRightOption" : false
        }, 
        {
            "providedOption" : "some option 3",
            "isRightOption" : true
        }, 
        {
            "providedOption" : "some option 4",
            "isRightOption" : false
        }   
    ]
}
```

What I am not sure is what I am doing wrong in the JSP that my data is not going through?

For making the form I used following site as reference

Site URL = https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/

insertques.jsp.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Question input page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="addquestion" method="post" action="/addques" enctype="application/json">
        <p>Question<input type="text" name="question"><br></p>

        Answer:<br>
        1. <input type="text" name="ansSet[0][providedOption]">
            <select name="ansSet[0][isRightOption]">
               <option value="true">true</option>
               <option value="false">false</option>
            </select>
            <br>
        2. <input type="text" name="ansSet[1][providedOption]">
            <select name="ansSet[1][isRightOption]">
               <option value="true">true</option>
               <option value="false">false</option>
            </select>
            <br>
        3. <input type="text" name="ansSet[2][providedOption]">
            <select name="ansSet[2][isRightOption]">
               <option value="true">true</option>
               <option value="false">false</option>
            </select>
            <br>
        4. <input type="text" name="ansSet[3][providedOption]">
            <select name="ansSet[3][isRightOption]">
               <option value="true">true</option>
               <option value="false">false</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
        <input type="reset" name="resetall">
        <input type="submit" name="submitform">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That isn't a valid `enctype` value. If you want to submit JSON you will have to use JavaScript to send it to the server.

Comment: Thanks  M. Deinum, What I want is convert my from data to JSON and so it can  be sent to server. for that can you refer any example or tutorial or any reading material. On net I see loads of content but not on the direction I want to work. This becoming very confusing  :(

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it directly you need to have a layer in place between your form and the service. For that, u need javascript to submit the form instead of direct submission.

JS:- you need to listen to form submit and stop the default form submission after that you can get form fields and send them as JSON.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $("#addquestion");
  $form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop default form submission 
    $.ajax({  // form submission via ajax
      url: $form.attr('action'), // form submission url
      type: 'POST', // request type
      dataType: 'json', // data type
      data: $form.serialize(), // get all data from the form
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result); // response back from server in case of success
      },
      error: function(xhr, resp, text) { // response back from server in case of failure 
        console.log(xhr, resp, text);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Do Read the Links for better understanding:-

- [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)
- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Thanks for your input. What I want is just to create JSON out of form. I understand the bit you shared but I am not getting how to convert the from object into json in clean way. (my knowledge in front end is very limited). I also want to understand even if my from is correct ans support the Json format I shared.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, I tried what you shared. It is giving me close to what I am looking for but not what I exactly I need. It is giving me 
{
  "question": "ttttdd",
  "ansSet": {
    "0": {
      "providedOption": "ad",
      "isRightOption": true
    },
    "1": {
      "providedOption": "asdf",
      "isRightOption": false
    },
    "2": {
      "providedOption": "rr",
      "isRightOption": false
    },
    "3": {
      "providedOption": "asdf",
      "isRightOption": false
    }
  }
}   

But if you see my structure it's not the same.

Comment: @sourav.ken can u post what output you are expecting ?

Comment: Following is the output I want: {
    "question" : "some long question",
    "ansList" : [
        {
            "providedOption" : "some option 1",
            "isRightOption" : false
        }, 
        {
            "providedOption" : "some option 2",
            "isRightOption" : false
        }, 
        {
            "providedOption" : "some option 3",
            "isRightOption" : true
        }, 
        {
            "providedOption" : "some option 4",
            "isRightOption" : false
        }   
    ]
}

Comment: @sourav.ken `var json = $("#addquestion").serializeToJSON({associativeArrays: false});`
and update your html form elements name to 
`<input type="text" name="ansSet[0].providedOption">
    <select name="ansSet[0].isRightOption">
-----
<input type="text" name="ansSet[1].providedOption">
    <select name="ansSet[1].isRightOption">`